# How to upload large data TSV into MySQL database for Springboot application?

Tags: spring-boot, database-migration

I have a SpringBoot application where my SQL code is present in XML migration scripts. One of the scripts loads data from a file into a MySQL database table. It was in the following format.

```
<changeSet id="load-some-data" author="author">
    <loadUpdateData encoding="UTF-8" file="data-file.tsv"
                    primaryKey="q_name" separator="\t" tableName="homology_data">
        <column name="q_name" type="STRING"/>
        <column name="chr" type="STRING"/>
        <column name="start" type="NUMERIC"/>
        <column name="end" type="NUMERIC"/>
        <column name="ref_base" type="STRING"/>
        <column name="hom_region" type="STRING"/>
        <column name="hom_region_var_location" type="STRING"/>
        <column name="base_in_hom_region" type="STRING"/>
        <column name="pident" type="NUMERIC"/>
        <column name="strand" type="STRING"/>
        <column name="gapped_alignment" type="STRING"/>
        <column name="created_at" type="DATE"/>
        <column name="updated_at" type="DATE"/>
    </loadUpdateData>
</changeSet>
```

It was earlier working fine with a small dataset of 200MB. The full dataset file is 19GB in size, when I am plugging in that file and starting up the Springboot application, then the application run fails with "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".

What other approaches can I take to synchronize the data upload with the application start?

Comment: split the tsv in smaller pieces or increase the memory of the system

Comment: You can use GZIP compression with SpringBoot. That seems appropriate, though it only postpones the OutOfMemory deadline.

Comment: My guess is that the database migration is trying to read the entire file into memeory